# Laravel OAuth token for one user only

Tags: php, api, laravel, oauth, laravel-5

I am creating a Web App where I need to access an API from Mobile Apps. I have implemented some Public API methods, which are fine and work great.

Now, I am working on the restricted API methods i.e. updating User info etc.

I have started implementing the [OAuth server package](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) `lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel`

It is all setup and dishing out tokens no problem, using the documentation from the GitHub repo and [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@mshanak/laravel-5-token-based-authentication-ae258c12cfea#.waqgq11z2).

I can get an OAuth token using a POST call to my public API method `oauth/access_token`, this returns an Access Token no problem.

**Now, my issue is:**

Once I have the Access Token, how do I know who it was issued to and what they have access to? There is no user_id associated with this token.

Can I simply create a column in the table and use Eloquent models to find out and how would I associate this token with a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after scouring the Source Code and documentation many times I gave up and posted a question here. I then thought "one more time". I found [this gem](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/blob/master/docs/resource-server/securing-endpoints.md).

And right down the bottom (not in TOC or anything) is:

## Finding access token owner

```
use LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Facades\Authorizer;

Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId();
```

Pair this with:

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
```

Like so:

```
Route::get('protected', ['middleware' => 'oauth', function() {
    $user_id = Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId();
    $user = \App\User::find($user_id);
    return $user; 
}]);
```

And Bob's your uncle. We have who made the request.